# How to allow socket.io traffic go through an Azure Web Application Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-waf

We apply the Azure Application Gateway Web Application Firewall (WAF) to provide additional preventions against malicious attacks such as SQL Injection, Cross-Site Scripting, etc on an Azure App Service. However, when I put the WAF in `prevention mode`, socket.io traffic are also getting blocked. I'm looking for the right exclusion rule to allow socket.io traffic to go through.

What exclusion rules should I use?

Comment: check if there's something related to Web Sockets